# Attach or detach appender at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I'm using XML configuration for log4net. I have the following appender-refs:

```xml
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="OldRollingLogAppender" />
</root>
```

(I also have these these appenders defined in the XML—their exact implementation shouldn't matter.)

I'd like to, at runtime, remove `OldRollingLogAppender`, and create and add a new one called `NewRollingLogAppender`. How do I do this?

A minimal working example would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting the root logger and then add and remove the appenders:

Remove:

```
var root = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
root.RemoveAppender(xxx);
```

Add:

```
var root = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
root.AddAppender(xxx);
```

You can iterate the list of appenders with root.Appenders
  https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/AllMembers_T_log4net_Repository_Hierarchy_RootLogger.htm

Comment: This doesn't work.  Nothing happens.  Is there a specific time when I have to call this? Are there any special flags I need to set, or any other magical things that I'm missing?

Comment: Update: If I do this *before* calling CreateLogger, I get an empty log file. If I call this *after*, no changes.

Comment: This should work but you will need to Close() on the appender after removing it.

Comment: I found a few things: (1) I first have to call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`, so the configuration is loaded into memory...*then* I can attempt to add or remove appenders.  (2) After I do so, I have to call `(Hierarchy)(LogManager.GetRepository()).RaiseConfigurationChanged(EventArgs.Empty)`.

Comment: I also found: (3) when *adding* an appender, I wasn't able to add one that was defined in the XML, I had to re-define it in code.  Perhaps I'm missing something.  (4) When *removing* an appender, the issue I'm still having is that calling XmlConfigurator *creates an empty log file* for an appender before I have had a chance to disable it.

Comment: Sorry if that's confusing—the point is it's not as simple as the code you listed.

Comment: I managed to get my stuff working, thanks!  I may have an uncommon use case, so I put all my my additional findings as a separate answer,

Answer (score 1):

In additon to Peter's answer, I had to do the following:

1) *Before* Adding or Removing, I had to call:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure()
```

Without doing this first, log4net would not let me remove any old appenders.

2) When Adding a new appender, I had to create an appender at runtime—in C#—I couldn't extract it from the XML. (Though...that may still be possible...I may have just been doing it wrong.) I.e.,

```
PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
patternLayout.ConversionPattern = ...;
patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

RollingFileAppender serviceAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
serviceAppender.Name = "NewRollingLogAppender";
serviceAppender.File = ...;
serviceAppender.DatePattern = ...;
serviceAppender.AppendToFile = ...;
serviceAppender.StaticLogFileName = ...;
serviceAppender.Layout = patternLayout;
serviceAppender.ActivateOptions();
```

3) *After* all of my Adding/Removing code was done, I had to call:

```
(Hierarchy)(LogManager.GetRepository()).RaiseConfigurationCh‌​anged(EventArgs.Empt‌​y);
```

Without doing this, log4net would not pick up the changes.

4) I observed that, `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` is called, it will create-and-lock whatever log file was associated with the old (i.e., to-be-removed) appender. I didn't want this to happen. To get around this, I had to create a custom appender which overrides `OpenFile`, `CloseWriter`, and `Append`.That way, I could at runtime decide whether or not to "opt-out" of this appender before calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`.